# Javascript Mediator In Browser Can't Find Instance Variables

Tags: javascript, html, class, constructor, this

Am working on a HTML/JS Mediator that filters a data_model when a user enters text to a field.  Have used window.onload = init, and spent four hours  trying to find why 'this' in the browser makes it print the calling object, and thus I can't get a class instance to refer to itself using 'this'

```
console.log(this.text_field)
```

in setup_list_view() works fine, seemingly because it's within the constructors scope.  Running it outside the constructor, as per below, gives:

```
Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined at HTMLInputElement.handle_text_field_changed
```

...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>

    <script>
        function init() {
            var text_field = document.getElementById("text-field");
            var list_view = document.getElementById("list-view")
            form_mediator = new FormMediator(text_field, list_view)
        }

        class FormMediator {
            constructor(text_field, list_view) {
                this.setup_text_field(text_field)
                this.setup_list_view(list_view)
            }

            setup_text_field(text_field) {
                this.text_field = text_field;
                this.text_field.onchange = this.handle_text_field_changed
            }

            setup_list_view(list_view) {
                this.data_model = ['England', 'Estonia', 'France', 'Germany']
                this.list_view = list_view
                this.list_view.innerHTML = this.data_model
            }

            does_string_start_with_text_field_text(text) {
                return false;
                return text.startsWith('E')
            }

            handle_text_field_changed(){
                this.list_view.innerHTML = 'new content' //this.data_model.filter(this.does_string_start_with_text_field_text)
            }
        }



        window.onload = init
    </script>

    <input id="text-field"><button>Search</button>
    <span id="list-view"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code occurs in this line:

```
this.text_field.onchange = this.handle_text_field_changed
```

A method, by default, won't carry its original binding context if assigned to a variable or another object's property. You need to bind this handle_text_field_changed method first, this way:

```
this.text_field.onchange = this.handle_text_field_changed.bind(this)
```

Comment: Hey @alcides-queiroz-aguiar , thanks for this. Indeed, doing your suggestion made the <input> call handl_text_field_changed :)  I then had to also change handle_text_field_changed to             handle_text_field_changed(){
                this.list_view.innerHTML = this.data_model.filter(this.does_string_start_with_text_field_text.bind(this))
            }
Regards